# Mootools1.1 what is element.$tmp?

Tags: javascript, mootools

i see it

```
function(element)
{
  element.$tmp.myTitle = 'title';
  element.$tmp.myText = 'text';
}
```

anybody know ?

when i bring this function to use in mootools1.2 it not define $tmp

$tmp?

use for Tips plugin mootools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was used in mootools 1.1 to store values on a DOM element (the tooltip in your case). Since mootools 1.2, the store() and retrieve() methodes are used for this, cause it will prevent you for creating memory leaks, caused by circular references.

http://mootools.net/blog/2008/01/22/whats-new-in-12-element-storage/